# Why is image file upload url in laravel giving me a 404 error?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I have built a simple backend structure with create,edit,update,view as you would usually setup with an mvc and laravel. Packages I am using are:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "codesleeve/laravel-stapler": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "dingo/api": "0.9.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
        "way/generators": "~3.0"
    },
```

Its working when adding data to forms and updating. The data structure is as follows:

```
"id": 1,
"name": "new offer",
"address": "test address",
"description": "test",
"offer_headline": "ccdd",
"offer_subheader": "hhhghhg",
"offer_terms": "test",
"map_location": "14,57",
"image": "/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/storage/app/uploads/2015-07-28-14:16:10-Screen Shot 2014-09-11 at 10.26.15.png",
"phone_number": "**************",
"website": "www.****.uk",
"created_at": "2015-07-28 14:16:10",
"updated_at": "2015-07-28 14:16:10",
"is_featured": false
```

My controller to do this is setup in quite a simple manner with a store method as you can see below. My image upload is handled with the Store in laravel filesystem and I use image intervention to resize the image. The image gets saved to the database as you can see and the url in the db is this: `/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/storage/app/uploads/` the issue is when I go to my finder to look for the file, it's not there or it's not been moved. My controller is below:

**I have left in the relevant parts to this**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Offer;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\OfferTransformer;
use Redirect;
use Image;
use DB;
use Request;
use Storage;
use File;

class OffersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */


    /**
    * Return all api methods here
    **/
    public function apiIndex()
    {
        //
        $this->middleware('auth');
        return Offer::all();
    }

    public function apiShow($id)
    {
        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
        return $this->response->array($offer->toArray());
    }



    public function index()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $offers = Offer::all();
        return view('offers.index', compact('offers'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(Offer $offer)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        return view('offers.create', compact('offer'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */

    public function store(Offer $offer)
    {

        $data = Input::except('image');
        $validation = Validator::make($data, Offer::$rules);


        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', $validation->errors());
        } else {
            $file = Input::file('image');

            $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(600, 600)->save(storage_path('app/uploads/').$filename);

            // //$file = $file->move(public_path().'/images/offers/', time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
            // // GET THE FILE EXTENSION
            $data['image'] = storage_path('app/uploads/').$filename;

            Offer::create( $data );
            return redirect('offers')->with('message', 'Offer added!');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        //dd($offer->exists);
        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
        return view('offers.show', compact('offer'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit(Offer $offer, $id)
    {
        //
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
        return view('offers.edit', compact('offer'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Offer $offer, $id)
    {

        $offer = Offer::findOrFail($id);
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), array('_token','_method','image') );
        $file = Input::file('image');

        $filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$file->getClientOriginalName();
        Image::make($file->getRealPath())->resize(600, 600)->save(public_path().'/images/offers/'.$filename);

        // //$file = $file->move(public_path().'/images/offers/', time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName());
        // // GET THE FILE EXTENSION
        $input['image'] = public_path().'/images/offers/'.$filename;

        $offer->update($input);

        return Redirect::route('offers.show',$offer->id)->with('message', 'Offer updated.');
    }

}
```

Can anyone see why this would happen? Is it not being moved to the right place?

Comment: A wild guess,but that name might be hard to parse on retrieval.

Comment: Do you think I should maybe take off the dates at the start?

Comment: Debug it,try a really simple name

Comment: ..and dont forget the routing...

Comment: ThatMSG routing? I did not think that would need it?

Comment: interestingly when I upload to public folder and take off this "/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/public" and leave just images it works. Can this be done with routing at all?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated again per comments.**

It looks like you are saving the file to the storage area which typically isn't public. Try changing `storage_path` to `public_path`. You can then grab the relative path and store that in the db.

```
$relativePath = 'app/uploads/'.sanitize_file($filename);
Image::make($file->getRealPath())
  ->resize(600, 600)
  ->save(public_path().$relativePath);

$data['image'] = '/'.$relativePath;
```

You need to `chmod 755` or `chmod 775` the upload folder to allow the server to save files there, typically a bad idea, but people do it.

What I typically do is use the cloud storage to save the images to `S3` then serve them off of `CloudFront`. So I am not 100% sure what I would do serving them off of the same web server.

I forgot that str_slug strips the `.` as well. I use this helper function to sanitize files.

```
if (!function_exists('sanitize_file')) {
    function sanitize_file($string, $force_lowercase = true, $anal = false)
    {
        $strip = array("~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", 
                       "(", ")", "_", "=", "+", "[", "{", "]", "}", "\\",
                       "|", ";", ":", "\"", "'", "&#8216;", "&#8217;",
                       "&#8220;", "&#8221;", "&#8211;", "&#8212;",
                       "â€”", "â€“", ",", "<", ">", "/", "?");
        $clean = trim(str_replace($strip, "", strip_tags($string)));
        $clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', "-", $clean);
        $clean = ($anal) ? preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $clean) : $clean;
        return ($force_lowercase) ?
            (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) ?
                mb_strtolower($clean, 'UTF-8') :
                strtolower($clean) :
            $clean;
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said above the image gets moved to the correct place. If I remove `/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/public` from the image url when uploading to public I can see the image correctly. In storage I can see the image in my finder but its not showing up in the page.

Comment: I also just realised that `/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/` is part of the vagrant virtual machine so the url is not actually there is virtual so I need to be able to just save to the relative path to be honest

Comment: @Mdunbavan OK try this.

Comment: I am getting `Can't write image data to path (/home/vagrant/projects/scoff/scoff-api/public/app/uploads/2015-07-28-15-46246205-1caa2bcb16-ojpg)` think its missing a dot at the end .jpg

Comment: I think `str_slug` is getting rid of the . before the jpg

Comment: thanks for this much appreciated. In the end I took your approach but I modified it slightly to remove the part of the url that was causing the issue, not sure it will work on production yet but I am sure I can build something in. Here is the gist file https://gist.github.com/mdunbavan/a05802e9cd04db66484d